# Why do programs in Unix-like environments have numbers after their name?

Tags: unix, manpage

For example, when I run `man ioctl` the page says `IOCTL(2)` at the top. What does that mean? Is there an `IOCTL(1)`? And how does one navigate between these?

Comment: Here's a list of what the man page sections refer to. http://www.december.com/unix/ref/mansec.html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's the man page section.  From memory, section 1 is user programs, 2 is system calls, and 3 is standard C library calls, and 5 is file formats.

Wikipedia has the full explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).

Comment: The man page section was very useful in days of printed manuals. I still have the 4.1 BSD printed manuals in my office. (The section number also helps you know when you're calling into the kernel, versus making a library call.)

Comment: @Craig - also useful for disambiguating, as shown in eduffy's answer.

Answer (score 24):

That's the man page section number.  For example

```
 man printf
```

(should) Give you section 1, `printf` the bash command, while

```
 man 3 printf
```

gives you the C function `printf`.