# What is the meaning of man pages contaning e.g. git-branch(1)

Tags: linux

**Duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587676/why-do-programs-in-unix-like-environments-have-numbers-after-their-name/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587676/why-do-programs-in-unix-like-environments-have-numbers-after-their-name)**

For instance, if I type:

```
man ps
```

...and then scroll to the very end I see something like this:

```
SEE ALSO
     kill(1), w(1), kvm(3), strftime(3), sysctl(8)
```

How am I supposed to interpret this? I know that kill is another command but what's the meaning of (1)? Is there anything to this?

The git man page is riddle with these:

```
git-add(1), git-am(1), git-archive(1)
```

What is someone trying to tell me?

Comment: Exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587676/why-do-programs-in-unix-like-environments-have-numbers-after-their-name/587682#587682

Comment: I did look for a question, but didn't find one.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936/what-does-the-number-in-brackets-shown-after-unix-command-names-mean - with more stars ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access the man page for a given numbered section, type `man number command`

From `man man`

> 1. Executable programs or shell
>      commands
> 2. System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
> 3. Library calls (functions within program libraries)
> 4. Special files (usually found in /dev)
> 5. File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
> 6. Games
> 7. Miscellaneous  (including  macro packages and conven‐tions), e.g.
>      man(7), groff(7)
> 8. System administration commands> (usually only for root)
> 9. Kernel routines [Non standard]

So for example,

```
man 1 printf
```

Will give you the page for the shell printf command, whereas

```
man 3 printf
```

Will give you the page for the C library call.

Answer (score 2):

The man pages are divided into sections, e.g. for system calls, commands, macros etc. mainly to prevent name conflicts, e.g. when a system call has the same name as a command.

One example for this is `sleep`:

```
man 1 sleep
```

versus

```
man 3 sleep
```

[Section 1](http://linux.die.net/man/1/) is reserved for user commands.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `man` are divided into several sections:

1. Commands available to users
2. Unix and C system calls
3. C library routines for C programs
4. Special file names
5. File formats and conventions for files used by Unix
6. Games
7. Word processing packages
8. System administration commands and procedures

So `kill(1)` is about a command but `strftime(3)` is about a C routine.

Answer (score 0):

Man pages are divided into sections. For example section 1 has commands and 2 has system calls.

If you run man kill it finds kill(1) which is the command.

If you run man 2 kill it shows you the system call also named kill.

Same goes for crontab(1) and crontab(5).

Answer (score 0):

As other say, man pages are divided into sections. `git-branch(1)` refers to the man page named `git-branch` in the section 1 of manual. You access this specific man page with one of the two commands (depending of your flavour of man):

```
man 1 git-branch
```

or

```
man -s 1 git-branch
```

Moreover, some items can appear in several sections, with different meanings, e.g., `printf(1)` and `printf(3)`. Typing:

```
man printf
```

displays man page for the first item found, depending of the order of your `MANPATH` environment variable. You can reorder `MANPATH` for changing your priority of sections or use:

```
man -a printf
```

for displaying all man pages for `printf`.