# PROGNAME(x) references in manpages -- What does the digit in ()s mean?

Tags: unix, manpage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do programs in Unix-like environments have numbers after their name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587676/why-do-programs-in-unix-like-environments-have-numbers-after-their-name)

I have seen several programs, such as `GREP(3)` and `PING(8)`, listed in manpages.  What is the significance of the digit in ()s?

Comment: FWIW, to whoever voted to close this, anything related to man pages is definitely programming related.  How can anybody program in unix without man pages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you run `man man` you will see the following information in the man page:

```
1   Executable programs or shell commands
2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
6   Games
7   Miscellaneous (including macro  packages  and  conven‐
    tions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Some names are associated with multiple entries, eg on my system 'sleep' has an entry in section 1 and an entry in section 3.  You can specify the one you want with e.g.

```
man 3 sleep
```

Sometimes I just guess with

```
man -a sleep
```

which displays each entry associated with sleep in turn.  I just go through them until I find the one I want.  You can also try

```
man -k sleep
```

to get a slightly bigger listing of pages involving the term 'sleep'

Comment: +1 I would mention that grep is (1), not (3), but you've got an explanation of what's usually where, so that's probably close enough.

Comment: It's possible that a system could have a grep(3) installed.  You are right that the command line grep that we know and love is grep(1).

Answer (score 5):

The number indicates which section the manpage is in. For your examples:

```
grep(3)
```

To get the documentation, type

```
man 3 grep
```

More commonly, if there is no `grep(2)` or `grep(1)`, you can get away with

```
man grep
```

However, I should note that `grep` is in section 1. Section 3 is generally reserved for C functions. An example is `getopt`: `getopt(1)` refers to the command-line utility `getopt`, but `getopt(3)` refers to the C function `getopt`. Likewise, `read(1)` is a program that reads from standard input, but `read(2)` is a POSIX system call for use in programs - it is one of the lowest-level forms of input you can get on most Linux (and other Unix) systems.

Comment: Not all versions of "man" support an unadorned section name. Solaris in particular would think you're asking about a command named 3. Use the "-s" option to remove doubt. It also has sections that aren't just numbers, including 3c and 3socket.

Answer (score 1):

It's to tell you what man page section help is in... 8 is typically the location of Administrative related utilities (/sbin, /usr/sbin, etc.)

So help for GREP(3) is in man page section 3, and you could type `man 3 grep` to get the help for grep(3) directly.