# What does grep(1) in manual of grep means?

Tags: unix, manpage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do programs in Unix-like environments have numbers after their name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587676/why-do-programs-in-unix-like-environments-have-numbers-after-their-name)

```
GREP(1)
```

I see this when i man grep, what does the 1 mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587676/why-do-programs-in-unix-like-environments-have-numbers-after-their-name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

grep(1) means grep is a command line.  There are 8 categories of man pages:

1. General Commands
2. System Calls
3. Subroutines
4. Special Files
5. File Formats
6. Games
7. Macros and Conventions
8. Maintenence Commands

thta's the number you see in man