# How to get further information on SIGFPE signal?

Tags: c, unix, signals, posix, bsd

This is from **The GNU C Library Reference Manual**

> int SIGFPE
>
> The SIGFPE signal reports a fatal arithmetic error. This signal
>   actually covers all arithmetic errors, including division by zero and
>   overflow.
>
> BSD systems provide the SIGFPE handler with an extra argument that
>   distinguishes various causes of the exception. In order to access
>   this argument, you must define the handler to accept two arguments,
>   which means you must cast it to a one-argument function type in order
>   to establish the handler.

But there is no example on how to **access the extra argument**.

I did my google work but could not find anything.

How can I get this extra information?

Comment: Same way you access any function argument -- by the name you gave the formal parameter.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry I am not very experienced with System Programming and C. What do you mean by your comment?

Comment: Why not use `sigaction()` rather than the obsolete(ish) `signal()`, and enjoy the pleasures of getting a `struct siginfo*` full of goodness?

Comment: @RossRidge Fixed the tags, sorry.

Comment: @EOF I am really just reading the Manual right now.

Comment: @KorayTugay: When you define a function, you provide a signature which contains a type and name for each argument.  Inside that function, using that name (called a formal parameter) accesses the value passed by the caller (called an actual parameter).

Comment: @BenVoigt Can you at least give a simple example to this so I can understand? Examples are always better for me.

Comment: @KorayTugay: Every C program starts with `int main(int argc, char** argv)` and you access the arguments by their names `argc` and `argv`.  When you create a function to handle your signals, you will give names to the arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As EOF mentioned in the comments, the much better way to do this, that doesn't require formally broken casts, and a bonus is correctly documented, is to install your signal handler using `sigaction` and the `SA_SIGINFO` flag, and then in the `si_code` field of the second parameter (type `siginfo_t`) you can determine which floating-point error occurred:

> The following values can be placed in `si_code` for a `SIGFPE` signal:
>
> **`FPE_INTDIV`**
>             Integer divide by zero.
>
> **`FPE_INTOVF`**
>             Integer overflow.
>
> **`FPE_FLTDIV`**
>             Floating-point divide by zero.
>
> **`FPE_FLTOVF`**
>             Floating-point overflow.
>
> **`FPE_FLTUND`**
>             Floating-point underflow.
>
> **`FPE_FLTRES`**
>             Floating-point inexact result.
>
> **`FPE_FLTINV`**
>             Floating-point invalid operation.
>
> **`FPE_FLTSUB`**
>             Subscript out of range.

Source: [Linux sigaction(2) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)

The same list is also readily available on the [FreeBSD siginfo man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=siginfo).

Comment: What is the (2) in the function name?

Comment: @KorayTugay: A manual section.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587676/why-do-programs-in-unix-like-environments-have-numbers-after-their-name

Comment: This is another explanation of the `(2)`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/62936/103167

Answer (score 1):

The information that glibc refers to is a historic mechanism, and is not portable. On FreeBSD, the [sigvec(2)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sigvec&sektion=2) manual page includes a notation that it is only supported on the VAX-11 architecture:

> On    the VAX-11 The handler routine can be declared:
>
> ```
> void  handler(sig, code, scp)
> int sig, code;
> struct sigcontext *scp;
> ```
>
> Here sig is the signal number, into which the hardware faults and traps
>       are mapped    as defined below.  The code argument is either a constant as
>       given below or, for compatibility mode faults, the    code provided by the
>       hardware (Compatibility mode faults are distinguished from    the other
>       SIGILL traps by having PSL_CM set in the psl).  The scp argument is a
>       pointer to    the sigcontext structure (defined in `<signal.h>`), used to
>       restore the context from before the signal.

The mapping list is not actually provided in this version of the manpage. It can be found in the [4.3BSD-Reno signal(3) manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=signal&sektion=3&manpath=4.3BSD+Reno). It's worth noting that this text is 25 years old.

On modern systems, you should use the sigaction mechanism, which is much more well-defined and portable.

> BUGS - This manual page is still confusing.

Indeed it is.